# Condition to use polymorphism

Tags: java, c#

is polymorphism only possible when there is a scenario of inheritance or is the implementation of polymorphism not dependent on inheritance.

Or is polymorphism mainly usefull when there is inheritance ?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @David - you *did* read the Wikipedia article on [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))?  Only the third type (subtyping) goes into inheritance. Dynamic/ad-hoc polymorpshim and parametric are found in several languages that do not include inheritance.

Comment: Actually, even the third one is about *subtyping*, and not inheritance. In Java and C# those two are conflated, but they are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Already answered: [Is polymorphism possible without inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11732581/697630)

Answer (score 4):

Polymorphism in computer science is a broader term than your question suggests:

- adhoc polymorphism, supported as function overloading;
- parametric polymorphism, as realized in generic containers like `List<T>`;
- dynamic polymorphism, or subtyping, which relies on the Liskov substitution principle.

Only the last form is based on inheritance. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29

Comment: Does Java support all of these sets of polymorphism that you have mentioned ?

Comment: @David: This is a question-and-answer site. If you have a question, **post it as a question**.

Answer (score 4):

Polymorphism is unrelated to inheritance.

There are different kinds of polymorphism:

- *Parametric Polymorphism*: here, a subroutine is parameterized over a type, meaning it doesn't know *anything* about the type. If it doesn't know anything, then it obviously also doesn't know about any inheritance relationship. Examples are a subroutine to compute the length of a list, it doesn't need to know anything about the types of the *contents* of the list. (Another common name for this kind of polymorphism is *Generics*.)
- *Ad-Hoc Polymorphism*: contrary to parametric polymorphism, where the subroutine doesn't care about the type and behaves identical for every type, with ad-hoc polymorphism, there are ad-hoc implementations of the subroutine for every type, so that the subroutine behaves *differently* for each type. (Another common name for this kind of polymorphism is *Overloading*.)
- *Inclusion Polymorphism*: this implies some kind of subtype relationship. (Note: subtyping is *not* the same as inheritance, even though languages like Java and C# confuse the two. In OCaml, for example, they both exist but are different and distinct concepts.) Inclusion polymorphism means that an instance of a subtype can be treated as an instance of a supertype. (The Liskov Substitution Principle tells us how to make sure that is safe.) (Another common name for this kind of polymorphism is *Subtype Polymorphism*.)

Inheritance *can* be used in ad-hoc polymorphism to share code between different implementations of subroutines to avoid code duplication. But it is purely a method for reducing code duplication, it is neither necessary nor sufficient for ad-hoc polymorphism.

Answer (score -3):

If you haven't heard of Dependency Injection - I think it's worth taking a look at.  Implementing DI really helped me get a better feel for polymorphism, constructing / testing instances or objects, etc.  Here are a few good tutorials:

[DI For Beginners](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1321158/A-beginners-guide-to-Dependency-Injection)

[Basic structure / surface concepts](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html)

Comment: this doesn't even attempt to answer the question asked: "is polymorphism mainly usefull when there is inheritance?"

Comment: Well, noticing that everyone gave info regarding the same thing - I thought I would provide info towards something else that was sort of relevant - no it wasn't a direct answer; why give another re-worded outline of definitions? You don't think that learning different concepts like DI would educate someone on how these things work? My bad..